# Cassandra : Pool is busy (no available connection and timed out after 10000 MILLISECONDS))

Tags: cassandra, connection-pooling

I've been trying to add rows to a cassandra table for a while but it keeps sending me the same error message after a few seconds : *Pool is busy (no available connection and timed out after 10000 MILLISECONDS))*

I still have a few rows inserted (a hundred) but it stops quickly

I tried to change a few poolingoptions but it didn't change much:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();//
        poolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768);
        poolingOptions.setPoolTimeoutMillis(10000);
        poolingOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 8);
        poolingOptions.setMaxQueueSize(20);
        poolingOptions.setIdleTimeoutSeconds(20);
```

Any idea of what I can do ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is the load of your cassandra cluster?

Comment: The load of my cassandra cluster is 7.6 Go

Comment: I meant 'load' in terms of CPU load. Looks like the cluster is too busy to accept new connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set core connections to max.

```
val poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions()
    .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1, 2)
    .setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32768)
    .setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 2)
```

You can set configurations according to your requirement. Like, how much maximum request can come. Current configuration can manage around 50K requests.
For more information [refer](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/pooling/)